# REST Api not working when trying to move file from one folder to other in the document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I tried to move the file from one folder to other folder using HTTP REST API call through SharePoint designer 2013 workflow, it got hanged with the workflow status as "Active". The URL length may got exceed to maximum but since it is SharePoint online it should allow maximum length of 400 characters as per my understanding.

Since my URL length is 252 characters, I don't know what is the mistake at my end.

Please let me know the maximum length URL in calling REST API from the designer workflow.

Whereas it is working fine for the URL length of 232 characters

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's SharePoint designer that is at fault here. Can you try creating the same workflow in Microsoft Flow. I'm not sure if this could be a solution, but worth giving a shot.

Comment: Yes probably it would work when using Flow. But the requirement is to acheive through SharePoint designer workflow

Comment: SP designer is a requirement? Sorry to know that. Usually its the outcome of events and workflows that becomes the requirement. If you can convince the business to get the same results using Flow, your problem could be solved, especially if they get the same outcomes. Just my 2c.